# Finding out what takes up so much space (encryption related)

Tags: encryption

so I just followed this guide to remove my home encryption:

http://pastebin.com/ntnLBfcr

But apparently there is something on my partition that takes up about 22GB of space (which is the same amount that the encryption folder did) and I can't for my life find out how to delete it. I've backed up my home folder in another HDD.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmqND.png

Help is incredibly appreciated, I'm frankly stumped.

So, in short:

Apparently something takes up space on my partition without it showing up in the / folder or any of its subfolders, how can I find it and delete it?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following command: `du -h -d 1 / | grep -v du | pastebinit`? PS: it can take a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was a silly one and I have solved it.
I simply had put my .Private folder inside the trashcan as root and not actually removed it. The program ran under my regular user and did thus not check root's trashcan, which is why I could not see what took up all this space.